# Change of the color of the hair in a render video

Tags: animation

I am working in blender and planning to create a character where the hair changes from black to white. I want to make an animated video which shows the change happens from the beginning of the hair, gradually to the end. I took the idea from the Disney animated movie, Tangled, when Rapunzel’s hair glows in a gradual way.Thanks for every help;))

Answer (score -1):

You can get a MixRGB node, plug it into the color of your shader, slap a color ramp on the factor of the MixRGB and put a gradient texture on the factor of the color ramp. Slide the colors around in the color ramp and you get a nice transition. :D

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. just wanna ask, I don’t want the change happens from all the sides of the hair in the same time ... like to begin from the roots to the middle of the hair till the end?

Comment: You can try using a color ramp. I'm kinda lazy to do it right now so I'll see if I can make one later.

Comment: Hi Rogue, how have you progressed in your research? I would really like to the see the effect of the color ramp, since this would answer the question.

Comment: @Leander oh damn i forgot about this, it's edited now.